# Dataframe has NAs instead of values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe loaded from an Excel file. It is similar to this:

```
Gender Country Effect Use Products

Male   UK      1      2   7
Female USA     2      4   6
Male   Russia  3      5   2
Female China   4      2   3
Male   China   3      1   6
Female USA     2      5   2
Male   UK      3      3   1
Female Russia  4      1   7
```

I want to calculate the mean per Country, like in the example below (excluding Gender):

```
Country Effect Use Products

UK      3      2   7
USA     2      4   4
Russia  3      5   5
China   4      2   4
```

I used the similar code to perform this operation (where "d" is name of the database):

```
country_avg <- aggregate(d[, 3:5], list(d$`Country `), mean)
```

However, instead of the desired output, the outcoming database looks like this:

```
Group1 Effect Use Products

UK      NA     NA  NA
USA     NA     NA  NA
Russia  NA     NA  NA
China   NA     NA  NA
```

The numbers in my dataframe are not identified as numeric values (I've tested that using is.numeric).
Moreover, R returns a lot of the following warning messages:

```
1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Please let me know how could I possibly fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the backquote as it also includes a space as suffix which may not be there in the original data column name.

```
aggregate(d[, 3:5], list(d$Country ), FUN =  mean)
```

Or use the formula method which gives the names as in the original data for the grouping column

```
aggregate(.~ Country, d[-1], FUN = mean)
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(Gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female"), Country = c("UK", "USA", 
"Russia", "China", "China", "USA", "UK", "Russia"), Effect = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Use = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
3L, 1L), Products = c(7L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 7L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. It seems to me that numbers in my dataframe are not identified as numeric. Is there a way to convert them into numeric values?

Comment: @SSG_08 Perhaps your original data have some non-numeric elements that convert it to character.  Try `d[, 3:5] <- lapply(d[,3:5], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` and then use the code

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yet, the result is still the same unfortunately. But apparently, I've found that R identifies the numbers in the database as a list. I am not sure how to convert list into numeric values though.

Comment: @SSG_08 The structure of your data is not clear.  Perhaps use `dput(d)` to show a reproducible example.  Otherwise, we think that it is a normal dataset based on what you showed

Comment: @SSG_08 May be you need `d[, 3:5] <- lapply(d[, 3:5], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x))))`